# force redirect page on load ancor link or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add javascript or anchor link to force redirect a page on page load after xxx seconds?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
</script>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://stackoverflow.com" />
```

if I insert this in the blog comment section the page sees it as plain text. how can i use ancor link to redirect a page in xxx seconds?

Comment: If you want to add javaScript, or HTML meta tag into some blog comments field, it is probably protected, tags are stripped or rendered as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `setTimeout()` can help you.
Here's your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; }, 3000); //Wait 3 seconds
</script>
```

Comment: how do i add this with comment section that has anchor text enabled.

Comment: Which comment section?